# How convert SQL query that used left join to Elastic DSL

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a sql query follow like this.

```
SELECT tt_0.* FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT SrcIp, DstIp, Count(*) AS cnt, MIN(time) FROM  tbl_log 
WHERE SubLogClass = "syslog" AND LogTime >= "11111111" GROUP BY SrcIp, DstIp) AS t0 WHERE cnt >= 1) AS tt_0 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT SrcIp, DstIp, Count(*) AS cnt, MIN(time) FROM tbl_log 
WHERE SubLogClass = "syslog" AND LogTime >= "22222222" GROUP BY SrcIp, DstIp) AS t1 WHERE cnt >= 1) AS tt_1 
ON tt_0.DstIp = tt_1.SrcIp AND tt_0.time <= tt_1.time WHERE tt1.SrcIp IS NOT NULL;
```

I really can't figure out how I can implement something like that with a single query.

I would appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: You can not perform joins(the traditional SQL style RDBMS joins) on elasticsearch directly.

Comment: So how do you perform a query from two results from two queries?

Comment: An efficient approach would be to change the way you store your data in elastic. NoSQL databases are not developed to handle relational data. You need not store data the same way as it is in MySQL.